# Fastlane (Gym) Mysteriously Seg Faults after Installing Fabric/Crashlytics

Tags: ios, react-native, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, fastlane

I'm working on a React Native iOS app. I've setup Fastlane, which has worked fine, building and uploading my app to iTunes connect. However upon installing Fabric/Crashlytics my Fastlane script fails on Gym. XCode still is able to build my app successfully. I've followed the Mac client instructions for setting up Fabric.

Fastlane version: 1.101.0
XCode version: 7.2.1
ReactNative version: 0.31.0

I have cleaned all my build artifacts since installing Fabric. I've been searching for a solution for several days, but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

[Output after running `fastlane beta` (fails on Gym)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAr1O.png)

[My Fastfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L27rn.png)

Comment: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5885

Comment: Fixed by upgrading from XCode 7.2.1 to XCode 7.3.1